# Dialogflow is making a wrong match

Tags: dialogflow-es

I need help on how the Dialogflow algorithm prioritizes entities.

For example:

The entity:

[
    {
        "value": "*1*",
        "synonyms": [
            "*AG101PL*"
        ]

When the user input is: *AG101PL*, the value which matches is: *1*, and the intent is set to: *AG101PL intent*.

But:

When the user input is: *S2_AG101PL*, the value which matches is still: *1*

The intent is rightly set to: *S2_AG101PL*

The entity:

[
{
        "value": "*2*",
        "synonyms": [
            "*S2_AG101PL*" ]

So the problem is that Dialogflow regonizes S2_AG101PL ***as*** AG101PL, and thus gives the wrong output when using $entity in the intent output

Does somebody have a solution for my problem?

It's for a Automatic dialog which gives product information about a speficied product (eg. AG101PL).

Already tried putting more synonyms, hoping that dialogflow prioritizes both 2 synonym matches in the same sentence or even putting S2_ and AG101PL in different entities. But still, no luck.

Comment: Can you give some context on what AG101PL and S2_AG101PL refer to, in real life? Flight numbers, license plate numbers, etc.

Comment: the AG101PL would be a product. The S2_AG101PL would be the the products with additional products.